# Using auto as the return value with my function in c++ isn't working in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am currently using CodeBlocks and for some reason it keeps giving me this weird error:

**error: expected type-specifier before 'decltype'**

I have tried various different source codes and it always gives me this error, I even copy and pasted one from my guide book and the same message appears..

For example this doesn't work:

```
template<class T, class U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u) // this is where the error occurs...
{
    return t + u;
}
```

Comment: Go to `Project->Build Options` and click the box that has `-std=c++11` in it.

Comment: I'm using an empty file right now, so it's greyed out, does this mean that I have to start a new project each time if I want to use c++11 syntax?

Comment: decltype and auto are C++11 features, you need to compile the code as C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your compiler does not support C++11, or that support is not enabled and you need to add some compiler options.  You haven't told use which compiler version you're using, so I can't say which of these two possibilities is the case.

With GCC or Clang, you enable C++11 by `-std=c++11`, or for older GCC versions, `-std=c++0x`.